# Use function later down in the script

Tags: javascript, jsx

You'll have to excuse me, I'm not very good at jsx and I'm struggling here.

I have a function that returns an array of pantone swatches, see below for the results of that array:

```
var spots = new Array(
    "PANTONE Yellow C", 
    "PANTONE Yellow 012 C",
);
```

I can display the result using alert but I can't work out how to use the array.

This is how I am generating the array:

```
main();

function main() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var selectedSwatches = doc.swatches;
    var pageNumber = 2;
    var count = 0;
    if (selectedSwatches.length > 0) {
        var text = 'var spots = new Array(\n';
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedSwatches.length; i++) {
            var swatch = selectedSwatches[i]
            var color = swatch.color;
            // Spot
            if (color.typename == "SpotColor") {
                count++;
                text += '"' + color.spot.name + '", ' + "\n";
                color = color.spot.color;
                if (count % 7 == 0)
                    pageNumber++;
            }

        }
        var textend = ');';
        var yepworking = text + textend;
        alert(yepworking)
    }
}
```

I now need to use the results from the alert as the following line uses the spots variable.

```
var pages = Math.ceil(spots.length/7);
```

And here's the final step in full;

```
var pages = Math.ceil(spots.length/7);
var Xoffset = 144;
var Yoffset = -684;
var lineLength = 19;

function makePages(){
    var cPage = 2;
    var shiftX = Xoffset * cPage;
    var shiftY = 0;
    var X = 1;
    var Y = 0;
    var pageOne = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("PAGE 2");
    while(cPage <= pages){

        if(X >= lineLength){
                X = 0;
                Y++;
        }
        cPage++;
        var nextPage = app.activeDocument.layers.add();
        nextPage.name = "PAGE " + cPage.toString();
        var content = pageOne.pageItems.getByName("LAYOUT");
        var newContent = content.duplicate();
        newContent.move(nextPage, ElementPlacement.INSIDE);
        newContent.textFrames.getByName("PAGE").contents = cPage.toString();
        newContent.translate(Xoffset*X,Yoffset*Y);
        X++;
    }
}

function fillPages(){
    var pCount = 2;
    var cCount = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i <= pages; i++){
            var cPage = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("PAGE " + pCount.toString());
            var layout = cPage.groupItems.getByName("LAYOUT");
            for(var j = 1; j < 8; j++){
                    var cBlock = layout.groupItems.getByName(j.toString());
                    if(spots[cCount]=="NextPage"){
                        cCount++;
                        break;
                    }
                    cBlock.textFrames.getByName("COLORNAME").contents = spots[cCount].replace("", "");
                    cBlock.pathItems.getByName("FILL").fillColor = app.activeDocument.swatches.getByName(spots[cCount]).color;
                    cCount++;
                    if(cCount >= spots.length){
                        return;
                    }
            }
            pCount++;
    }
}

makePages();
fillPages();
```

Basically, If I manually paste the array into the jsx file, it works but I can't get it to work without doing that?

Comment: If you define variables inside a function, the scope of the variables is that function alone.

Comment: Also... that's not how you define an array... that's how you generate a string that says array.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp Just define array like they are meant to be defined like. Dont generate a string you can't use

Comment: `var spots = [];
spots.push(spotOrsomething);`

Comment: Apologies but I'm just not getting this.  What do you mean 'Just define array and not generate a string'

Comment: your `var text` is TEXT, not array.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting this now. So by adding text before the if statement and again after means it;s a string and not an array, therefor I can't use it the way I would like. On this basis, how do I create an array using the if statement so that it can be used for math.ceil?

Comment: No, you are writing "Array(" to a variable. You are not generating an array. You dont deal with arrays. There's no arrays anywhere except the `selectedSwatches`. You dont create arrays using if statements and arrays have nothing to do with if statements

Comment: To define an array you write this: `var spots = [];` Not this: `var text = 'var spots = new Array(\n';`

Comment: To add an element to array you write this: `spots.push(element);` not this: `if (color.typename == "SpotColor") {
                count++;
                text += '"' + color.spot.name + '", ' + "\n";
                color = color.spot.color;
                if (count % 7 == 0)
                    pageNumber++;
            }`

Comment: Thank you for your help but i think i am well out of my depth here, do you have an example you can show me please?

Comment: Sure: 
`var spots = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedSwatches.length; i++) {
            var swatch = selectedSwatches[i]
            var color = swatch.color;
            // Spot
            if (color.typename == "SpotColor") {
                count++;
                spots.push(color.spot.name);
                color = color.spot.color;
                if (count % 7 == 0)
                    pageNumber++;
            }
            alert(JSON.stringify(spots));
        }
`

Comment: Hi, thank you for that, I do get an error though 'Json is undefined ' and it points towards: alert(JSON.stringify(spots));